The dependency order of function packages with the same name when building and compiling
robotck@robotckvrm:~/arm_ws$ echo $AMENT_PREFIX_PATH
/opt/ros/humble
robotck@robotckvrm:~/arm_ws$ colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --parallel-workers 3 
[1.606s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_selection:Some selected packages are already built in one or more underlay workspaces:
    'joint_trajectory_controller' is in: /opt/ros/humble
If a package in a merged underlay workspace is overridden and it installs headers, then all packages in the overlay must sort their include directories by workspace order. Failure to do so may result in build failures or undefined behavior at run time.
If the overridden package is used by another package in any underlay, then the overriding package in the overlay must be API and ABI compatible or undefined behavior at run time may occur.

If you understand the risks and want to override a package anyways, add the following to the command line:
    --allow-overriding joint_trajectory_controller

This may be promoted to an error in a future release of colcon-override-check.
Starting >>> joint_trajectory_controller
Starting >>> ur_dashboard_msgs
Starting >>> ur_description                                                
Finished <<< ur_description [0.39s]   
Starting >>> ur_msgs
Finished <<< ur_dashboard_msgs [1.82s]
Starting >>> ur_client_library
Finished <<< ur_msgs [1.55s]          
Starting >>> ur_moveit_config
Finished <<< ur_client_library [0.88s]
Finished <<< ur_moveit_config [0.87s] 
Finished <<< joint_trajectory_controller [3.38s]                      
Starting >>> ur_controllers
Finished <<< ur_controllers [15.9s]                        
Starting >>> ur_robot_driver
Starting >>> ur_bringup                         
Finished <<< ur_bringup [0.32s]                                       
Finished <<< ur_robot_driver [6.14s]                       
Starting >>> ur_calibration
Finished <<< ur_calibration [0.42s]                      
Starting >>> ur
Finished <<< ur [0.31s]                     

Summary: 11 packages finished [27.5s]

building log：
-- Found joint_trajectory_controller: 2.37.0 (/home/robotck/arm_ws/install/joint_trajectory_controller/share/joint_trajectory_controller/cmake)

but the $AMENT_PREFIX_PATH only have /opt/ros/humble, and i have not source ~/arm_ws/install/set.bash ,why colcon build can Found joint_trajectory_controller: 2.37.0 ,the joint_trajectory_controller
the version in /opt/ros/humble is : Found joint_trajectory_controller: 2.29.0 (/opt/ros/humble/share/joint_trajectory_controller/cmake)

i want to build ur relative packages using the joint_trajectory_controller: 2.37.0 when i source ~/arm_ws/install/set.bash, if not ,use joint_trajectory_controller: 2.29.0 .
